# Prevent iCloud Backup of Folder

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, backup, icloud

I recently got rejected for my NSLibraryDirectory backing up wrong kind of data to iCloud.  I am trying to prevent the entire directory from backing up to iCloud, as this directory doesn't contain anything but downloaded content.  Would this code in the AppDelegate.m work?

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

   NSURL *pathURL= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentsDirectory];
[self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:pathURL];
return documentsDirectory;

}

- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL

{ if (NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey) {
assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);



NSError *error = nil;

BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]

                              forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];

if(!success){

    NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);

}

return success;
}
else {
assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);



const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];



const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";

u_int8_t attrValue = 1;



int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);

return result == 0;
}

}
```

Comment: Ok, I changed a little bit up.  In the applicationDidFinishLaunchingOptions part I added:
`NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

   NSURL *pathURL= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentsDirectory];
[self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:pathURL];`
and then left the BOOL Code alone

Comment: You'll need to add the following to your header (.h) file to use the setxattr function: `#include <sys/xattr.h>`